# How to update my elements after adding an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

After reading the title, you might have known the problem. Let me elaborate: when I add an element using JavaScript, I can't do anything with that element. When the element is clicked, the element is supposed to do a certain function, but when I add the new element, just does nothing.

Code:

```
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-bar-title">Progress:</div>
        <div class="progress-bar-outline">
            <div class="progress-bar-percentage"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list" id="listSection">
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="new-button">Create</div>
    <div class="new-section">
        <input type="text" class="text-box" placeholder="Name for this card">
    </div>
```

```
//creates a new element
newText.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (newText.value != "") {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            let list_section = document.getElementById("listSection");
            let name = newText.value;

            let new_li = document.createElement("li");
            new_li.innerHTML = name;

            list_section.querySelector("ul").appendChild(new_li);

            let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
            newSection.classList.remove("opened");

            divs.forEach((div) => {
                if (div != newSection) {
                    div.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
                    div.style.filter = "";
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

//looping through each list to add that function
list_Sections.forEach((list) => {
    totalListCount++;
    list.addEventListener("click", () => {
        list.classList.toggle("checked"); //this function doesn't apply to the newly created element

        if (!list.classList.contains("checked")) {
            listCompleted--;
        } else {
            listCompleted++;
        }

        average = (listCompleted / totalListCount) * 500;
        percentage.style.width = average;
    });
});
```

Ask you have any questions about this topic.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add the HTML associated with the code?

Comment: Event listeners only apply to elements you've added them to. You have to add the event listener to the newly created element at creation time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Updated it to HTML

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new element is added, your code should attach the event listener to that new element. Try nesting your the code related to `.addEventListner()` inside the `keyup` event listener code.

```
newText.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (newText.value != "") {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            let list_section = document.getElementById("listSection");
            let name = newText.value;

            let new_li = document.createElement("li");
            new_li.innerHTML = name;

            list_section.querySelector("ul").appendChild(new_li);

            let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
            newSection.classList.remove("opened");

            divs.forEach((div) => {
                if (div != newSection) {
                    div.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
                    div.style.filter = "";
                }
            });

            //looping through each list to add that function
            list_Sections.forEach((list) => {
                totalListCount++;
                list.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    list.classList.toggle("checked"); 

                    if (!list.classList.contains("checked")) {
                        listCompleted--;
                    } else {
                        listCompleted++;
                    }

                    average = (listCompleted / totalListCount) * 500;
                    percentage.style.width = average;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: the old elements fails at achieving the functions